# How do I get the access_token from the omniauth callback response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linkedin-api, omniauth

I need to retrieve the access_token and access_token_secret in the controller response(create action) below. How do I do this?

routes.rb

```
  match "/auth/:provider/callback" => "sessions#create", via: :get
```

the view

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with LinkedIn", "/auth/linkedin" %>
```

session controller.

```
  def create
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort this out. The answer was in the [auth hash schema](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Auth-Hash-Schema).

```
access_token = auth["credentials"]["token"]
access_secret = auth["credentials"]["secret"]
```

I inserted this into my controller to retrieve and save the user profile. Great success!